# Converse of Taylor's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, functional-equations, approximation-theory

Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$.  From Taylor's Theorem, we know that any $n$-time differentiable function $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the condition that
$$f(x+h)=\sum_{k=0}^n\,\frac{f_k(x)}{k!}\,h^k+R_n(x,h)\text{ for all $x\in(a,b)$ and $h\in(a-x,b-x)$}\,,\tag{*}$$
where $f_k:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is the $k$-th derivative of $f$ for each $k=0,1,2,\ldots,n$ (in particular, $f_0=f$), and the $n$-th remainder term $R_n(x,h)$ satisfies
$$R_n(x,h)\in o\left(h^n\right)\text{ for each $x\in(a,b)$ and for every small $h\in\mathbb{R}$}\,.\tag{**}$$
(In other words, $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\,\dfrac{R_n(x,h)}{h^n}=0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.)

I have a question whether the converse of Taylor's Theorem is true.  In other words, is the following conjecture correct?

> **Conjecture.** Suppose that functions $f,f_0,f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfy (*) and (**).  Then, $f$ is $n$-time differentiable, with $k$-th derivative $f_k$ for each $k=0,1,2,\ldots,n$ (in particular, $f_0=f$).

From [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88501/converse-of-taylors-theorem), some continuity or boundedness constraints on the $f_k$'s or on the remainder term $R_n$ are assumed for the converse to hold.  If the converse does not hold in general (i.e., without these continuity or boundedness constraints), could anybody give a counterexample?  If it is true, then can you please give me a proof or a reference?  What I know is that the converse holds for $n=0$ (trivially) and $n=1$ (with a small amount of work).

Comment: Maybe [Borel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel's_lemma) could be of interest. Although, the function is assumed to be smooth in the statement of the lemma.

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding, functions like $f(x) = x^{n+1}\sin (x^{-n})$ (with $f(0) = 0$) are counterexamples (if $n > 1$). Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @DanielFischer  I am not sure.  Maybe my brain is a bit messed up today (not enough sleep last night).  But I have a feeling that maybe your example violates $R_{n}(x,h)\in o(x^n)$.  I could be wrong.  But if this is a counterexample for real, please post this as an answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $R_n(x,h)$ in $(\ast)$ rather than $R_k$, by the way? To know whether it's really a counterexample, I must be sure to understand your question correctly. Can we state your conjecture as follows: Suppose $f, f_0, \dotsc, f_n \colon (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ are functions such that the function $$R_n(x,h) = f(x+h) - \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{f_k(x)}{k!}h^k$$ defined for all $x,h$ with $x, x+h \in (a,b)$ satisfies $\lim_{h \to 0} h^{-n}R_n(x,h) = 0$ for every $x \in (a,b)$. Then $f$ is $n$ times differentiable?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ohhh, thanks, that was a typo.  I fixed it and hopefully other similar typos.

Comment: @DanielFischer And your version of the conjecture is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $n > 1$ we need some regularity assumptions on the $f_k$ (or on $R_n$). Without such assumptions, consider
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\qquad 0 &\text{if } x = 0 \\ x^{n+1}\sin (x^{-n}) &\text{if } x \neq 0\end{cases}$$
and
$$f_k(x) = \begin{cases}\quad 0 &\text{if } x = 0 \\ f^{(k)}(x) &\text{if } x \neq 0\end{cases}$$
for any interval with $0 \in (a,b)$. Outside the origin $f$ is analytic, hence the remainder term $R_n(x,h)$ is $o(h^n)$ for every $x \in (a,b) \setminus \{0\}$ (but the constants depend on $x$ of course). For $x = 0$ we find
$$\frac{R_n(0,h)}{h^n} = h\sin (h^{-n})\,,$$
thus $R_n(x,h) = o(h^n)$ for every $x \in (a,b)$. But $f$ is differentiable only once, since
$$f_1(x) = f'(x) = \begin{cases} \qquad 0 &\text{if } x = 0 \\ (n+1)x^n\sin(x^{-n}) - n \cos (x^{-n}) &\text{if } x \neq 0\end{cases}$$
isn't even continuous at $0$.

Comment: This counterexample eluded me for a very long time.  Now, I understand why there are boundedness/continuity (i.e., regularity) assumptions on $f_k$'s in the MathOverflow link.  Thank you!